# How would one make an Xcode style console window?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, console, terminal, nstextview

I am making a Haskell editor with Cocoa, and it would be useful to support some in-application text output. Even better would be supporting some text input.

Xcode does all this in its console, which looks like it might be an NSTextView, but not sure if somebody might have done all this before.

Comment: Sounds like one could use the same solution for a Cocoa version of Python's or Ruby's live interpreter.